# jQuery stop "click" action after first elevent

Tags: jquery

There are two nested elements, both have different `click` actions.
I need to stop outer element action when inner element is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id='out'>
    <div id='in'></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#out').click(function(){alert('OUT div is pressed')})
$('#in').click(function(){alert('IN div is pressed')})
```

I need when `in` is pressed, only his action is executed. `out`'s script should have no action.

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)():

```
$('#in').click(function(e){
   alert('IN div is pressed')
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[event.stopPropogation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
$('#out').click(function(){alert('OUT div is pressed')})
$('#in').click(function(event){
alert('IN div is pressed');
event.stopPropagation();
}
)
```

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#out').click(function(){
    alert('OUT div is pressed');
});
$('#in').click(function(){
    $('#out').unbind('click');
    alert('IN div is pressed');
});
```

or you could stop the propagation of the event, but you can't know for sure which event handler will be triggered first ([capture vs bubble events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)) :

```
$('#in').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('IN div is pressed');
});
```