# How to prevent click event to trigger show/hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a clickable layer. On click it reveals/hides some extra content. Within this layer there is a link which triggers another page to load in the browser.

When this link is clicked the clickable layer is clicked too because it contains the link. How can I avoid that?

I want the link to work but while the user clicks on it the extra content should not be shown.

I tried with

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
     return false;      
});
```

but this disables both hide/show and the link to work. Any ideas? Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkPLD/

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088339/jquery-stop-click-action-after-first-elevent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to avoid events bubbling up:

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```